# R: colSums & Mutate (Wrong Result Size)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to mutate colSums at the bottom of a dataframe, but the first column of the table is a character vector containing labels.

For example,

```
df=data.frame(
  label = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
  x1=c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(1,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,1,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,0,1))
```

Without the label col,

```
df %>% mutate(Total = colSums(df[, 1:5], na.rm = TRUE))
```

should work fine... but I tried

```
df %>% mutate(Total = colSums(df[, 2:6], na.rm = TRUE))
```

which gave me an error message

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :   wrong result size (5), expected
>   10 or 1

How can I ignore that first column and still mutate colSums into the bottom of my data frame?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are trying to do above is add another column with the column totals. This does not match with the number of rows (number of columns you are summing is not equal to the number of rows). So this is not appropriate. You can calculate the `colSums` and then add it as another row using `bind_rows`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutate` adds a new column to a data.frame.  You indicate you're trying to add a new row to the bottom.  Thus the error message: in trying to create a new column, `mutate` expects a vector of length 10 (or a single value that it can fill the entire column with).

If you want to add a totals row to a data.frame, try `janitor::adorn_totals("row")`:

```
library(janitor)

df %>%
  adorn_totals("row")

 label x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
     A  1  1  0  1  1
     B  0  1  1  0  1
     C  0 NA  0 NA NA
     D NA  1  1  1  1
     E  0  1  1  0  1
     F  1  0  0  0  1
     G  1 NA NA NA NA
     H NA NA NA  0  1
     I  0  0  0  0  0
     J  1  1  1  1  1
 Total  4  5  4  3  7
```

*Self-promotion disclaimer, I wrote the janitor package and this function - posting this answer because the function addresses precisely this situation.*

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `add_totals_row` is deprecated in favor or `adorn_totals` now (where you can specify `adorn_totals("row")` or `adorn_totals("col")`)